Lstlisting doesn't highlight keyword
I have the MWE below. However, the keyword \getit is not highlighted. How to turn it blue?
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\small,
        escapechar=|,
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        numbers=left,
        numbersep=5pt,
        backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
        commentstyle=\color{gray},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
        stringstyle=\color{green!75!black},
        morecomment=[f][\color{green!75!black}][0]{\%},
        morekeywords={\getit}
    }


\begin{document}
This is an example of code:

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]
\title{Put a title} %... identify your subject
\author{Your Name}  %... identify yourself
\year=2021          %... year you submitted your work
\getit
\end{lstlisting}



\end{document}



Have you tried without the \ in morekeywords ?

@daleif yes, I have. Does it work for you?

Was not at PC. But there seems to be a race condition, you need to set the language before addign morekeywords. if you move the langiage setting op into the conf, fx at the top, getit is colored for me.
